# How to show all images in a Drupal7 View photogallery?

Tags: drupal-7, photo-gallery

I have defined a custom content type where i added an Image field with unlimited images per row.
I would like to show in a single photogallery all the images contained in the table, but the Photogallery engines i tried (Galleria, Gallery formatter) show a gallery for every record, not what i need.

Is there a module that permits to show all the images inside a single Gallery?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more details about what you're looking for, I can only suggest the obvious: Use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to display all the images and theme accordingly.

If you're looking for a particular functionality, please indicate so in your question.  (ie. What do you want the Gallery to look like/to do that isn't currently achievable by just the Views module + theming?)

Comment: Using Views you get all the images files from the "files_managed" table, if that's the table you are talking about. Using Views (contextual) filters you can limit the output on a per node level.

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting you. If you want all images attached to content, you can try with [Photowall](http://drupal.org/project/photowall) module. Please do have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you are searching..
But following will help///

http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach

http://drupal.org/node/758724

Or search in the drupal modules. Definetly you'll find something.

Comment: Also you can download a similar module and change it to your need.